# Is it possible to use a ternary in one-line generator in python?

Tags: python

I have a csv dataset that I have to parse, where some data is missing.
Therefore, I'm looking for a way to replace them with zeroes.

What I achieved to do so far is to parse the file correctly and avoid the missing data, that makes the parsing stops at the first wrong data it encounter and ignore the next ones, even if they are correct.

```
[(year, population) for year, population in zip(years, parsed) if population != '']
```

I tried to add an else statement, which would result in a ternary, but it raises a syntax error,

Years is the list of fields and Parsed is the parsed data, that I want to zip together, to get a list of tuple.

Is there any way to replace this data with a similar syntax without using a dedicated library like csvreader (I'm learning, I don't want all to be done without having any clue of how it works) ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please share sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move if to the beginning to support else:

```
[(year, population) if population != '' else [Something] for year, population in zip(years, parsed)]
```

Comment: This is correct. The syntax for comprehensions does not allow else at the end since the else condition is to do nothing i.e don't add this item to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you mean by "the parsing stops ... ignores the next ones", because that is not how the `if` condition in a comprehension works. It's a filter that skips incorrect values, not a stop condition. For example, `[x for x in range(5) if x % 2]` will return `[1, 3]`, skipping the even values.

However, you can use a ternary expression inside the comprehension as well. This needs to be in the form `[expr1 if cond1 else expr1 for ... in ...]`, preceding the `for`.